# Battery animation: Reverse flow cycle, after first cycle

Tags: html, css

I am constructing the base of an animated battery charger indicator. (see attached code snippet). The aim is to solve it with pure html5 and css3 without involving javascript, library or other frameworks.

The problem is that after the first animation cycle, the animation changes order flow. See more details below. The wanted solution is that the infinite cycle is repeated exactly as the first cycle. Between the cycles the animation should have a short break with either white or transparent color.

---

During the first cycle of the animation it runs as expected:

- 1st - red (fade in) + black top pole (where black pole stays at the end of
  animation)
- 2nd - yellow (fade in)
- 3rd - green (fade in)

After the first cycle, the complete animation should disappear and repeat sequence of first cycle, since it is set to run infinite counts.

The behavior right now is:

- 1st cycle (as described above).

Rest of the cycles:

- step-1: all
  colors fades in at same time (red,yellow,green,black).
- step-2: colors
  fade out in following order (green,yellow, + black and red).

```css
/********/
/* Grid */
/********/

.wrapper {
  width: 180px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  1fr
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
  300px
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
    "battery-body"
    ;
}

/********/
/* Grid */
/********/

.battery-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  1fr
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
  40px
  40px
  40px
  40px
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
    "battery-part-1"
    "battery-part-2"
    "battery-part-3"
    "battery-part-4"
    ;
}

/**********/
/* Layout */
/**********/

.battery-body {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 80px;
}

.battery-part-1 {
  grid-area: battery-part-1;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  animation: black-top 8s 1s infinite;
}

/* Green */
.battery-part-2 {
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  animation: battery-level-green 6s 3s infinite;
}

/* Yellow */
.battery-part-3 {
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  animation: battery-level-yellow 7s 2s infinite;
}

/* Red */
.battery-part-4 {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  animation: battery-level-red 8s 1s infinite;
}

/*************/
/* Animation */
/*************/

@keyframes black-top {
  from {
  opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes battery-level-green {
  from {
  opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@keyframes battery-level-yellow {
  from {
  opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

@keyframes battery-level-red {
  from {
  opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="battery-body">
      <div class="battery-part-1"></div>
      <div class="battery-part-2"></div>
      <div class="battery-part-3"></div>
      <div class="battery-part-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/********/
/* Grid */
/********/

.wrapper {
  width: 180px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  1fr
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
  300px
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
    "battery-body"
    ;
}

/********/
/* Grid */
/********/

.battery-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  1fr
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
  40px
  40px
  40px
  40px
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
    "battery-part-1"
    "battery-part-2"
    "battery-part-3"
    "battery-part-4"
    ;
}

/**********/
/* Layout */
/**********/

.battery-body {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 80px;
}

.battery-part-1 {
  grid-area: battery-part-1;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  animation:black-top 5s 1s infinite;
}

/* Green */
.battery-part-2 {
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  animation: battery-level-green 5s 1s infinite;
}

/* Yellow */
.battery-part-3 {
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  animation: battery-level-yellow 5s 1s infinite;
}

/* Red */
.battery-part-4 {
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  animation: battery-level-red 5s 1s infinite;
}

/*************/
/* Animation */
/*************/

@keyframes black-top{
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33% ,100%{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: black;

  }
}

@keyframes battery-level-red  {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33%,100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: red;
  }
}


@keyframes battery-level-yellow {
  0%,33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66%,100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

@keyframes battery-level-green {
  0%,66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: green;
  }
}


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="battery-body">
      <div class="battery-part-1"></div>
      <div class="battery-part-2"></div>
      <div class="battery-part-3"></div>
      <div class="battery-part-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```